# Get all variations attributes with prices for a variable product in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, product-variations

There is a need to display Attribute Variations with their respect "Regular Price". However, despite trying, there is no success to display price. Please see the code below that displays the Variation Fine. Please help out to display the Price as well.

```
       //Getting product attributes
    $product_attributes = $product->get_attributes();

    if(!empty($product_attributes)){
        //Getting product attributes slugs
        $product_attribute_slugs = array_keys($product_attributes);
        $count_slug = 0;
        echo '<div class="product_attributes">';
        foreach ($product_attribute_slugs as $product_attribute_slug){
            $count_slug++;

            // Removing "pa_" from attribute slug and adding a cap to first letter
            $attribute_name =  ucfirst( str_replace('pa_', '', $product_attribute_slug) );
            //echo $attribute_name . ' (';

            $attribute_values = get_terms($product_attribute_slug);
            $count_value = 0;
            //print_r(array_values($available_variations));
            foreach($attribute_values as $attribute_value){
                $count_value++;
                $attribute_name_value = $attribute_value->name; // name value
                $attribute_slug_value = $attribute_value->slug; // slug value
                $attribute_slug_value = $attribute_value->term_id; // ID value
                echo $attribute_name_value;
            }
        }
        echo '</div>';
        //print_r(array_values($attribute_values));
    }
```

Comment: show full code, such as where did you defin `$product`?, where did you write your code? and etc

Comment: The code is part of the page where product description appears in wordpess/woocommerce. Only line of code missing here is on top where global $post, $product; is declared. Nothing else. I just could nnot seem to display price per variation however the name of the variation is appearing just fine.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can get all the data that you want for **all product variations** in a variable product this way:

```
if($product->is_type('variable')){
    foreach($product->get_available_variations() as $variation ){
        // Variation ID
        $variation_id = $variation['variation_id'];
        echo '<div class="product-variation variation-id-'.$variation_id.'">
            <strong>Variation id</strong>: '.$variation_id.'<br>';

        // Attributes
        $attributes = array();
        foreach( $variation['attributes'] as $key => $value ){
            $taxonomy = str_replace('attribute_', '', $key );
            $taxonomy_label = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy )->labels->singular_name;
            $term_name = get_term_by( 'slug', $value, $taxonomy )->name;
            $attributes[] = $taxonomy_label.': '.$term_name;
        }
        echo '<span class="variation-attributes">
            <strong>Attributes</strong>: '.implode( ' | ', $attributes ).'</span><br>';

        // Prices
        $active_price = floatval($variation['display_price']); // Active price
        $regular_price = floatval($variation['display_regular_price']); // Regular Price
        if( $active_price != $regular_price ){
            $sale_price = $active_price; // Sale Price
        }
        echo '<span class="variation-prices">
            <strong>Price</strong>: '.$variation['price_html'].'</span><br>
        </div>';
    }
}
```

This code is tested and works.